# Ошибка "ImportError: cannot import name 'Callable' from 'collections" при импорте из pyspectator.processor

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspectator

```
from pyspectator.processor import Cpu
from time import sleep
cpu = Cpu(monitoring_latency=1)
with cpu:
    for _ in range(8):
       cpu.load, cpu.temperature
       sleep(1.1)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\komp\Desktop\py.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyspectator.processor import Cpu
  File "C:\Users\komp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyspectator\processor.py", line 5, in <module>
    from collections import Callable
ImportError: cannot import name 'Callable' from 'collections' (C:\Users\komp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\collections\__init__.py)
```

Comment: код написан нормально  вылезает ошибка

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Похожая проблема: https://github.com/it-geeks-club/pyspectator/issues/30 Сам проект давно не обновлялся, скорее всего, имеет подобные проблемы на версии python 3.10